# What should I do when I am not sure my recommendation would fit

Tags: discussion, answer-quality, unanswered-questions

Sometimes I see questions where I have hardware in mind which will likely meet OPs requirements but where I cannot confirm this. For an example see [this question about RAID DAS](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/12021/external-2-5-2-bay-raid-usb3-enclosure-with-hdparm-udisksctl-power-off-support) and my discussion with OP in comments under question.

Is that answer fine? Or should I have left it as a comment?

Edit: the discussion in [Should we encourage users not to leave answers as comments?](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/638/should-we-encourage-users-not-to-leave-answers-as-comments) does not touch on this specific topic of *this hardware should be fine but I am not sure*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have information or a recommendation to contribute that has the potential to be helpful (to the OP, or to other future readers), err on the side of using an answer rather than a comment.

Comments are subject to fairly arbitrary deletion, based on the judgement of the moderator who happens to come across them. Particularly if you have a recommendation that you're reasonably sure of, put it in an answer to make it clear it's important information. If you turn out to be wrong, you can always edit to correct your answer, or delete it altogether if it's completely off-base.

Comment: Thought so, but wanted to make sure. One site which is extremely strict about the ban on answer comments is the Interpersonal Stack if you are interested in seeing how others do it. Although their reasons are much more serious.

Comment: @JanDorniak Aye, I hang around there from time to time. This site isn't quite that strict and I'm happy to be flexible on where the line is according to circumstance, but something that resembles an answer should, generally, be one.